# Is the "animated" boolean parameter in UIKit methods different than setting an animation duration?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, animation, uikit

I am implementing a method that has a boolean parameter called `animated` similar to many UIKit methods. To keep the implementation simple, I'd like to write:

```
- (void)showElement:(BOOL)animated
{
  CGFloat duration = animated ? 0.25 : 0;
  [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
    // animation code
  } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // completion code
  }];
}
```

Is this correct or is it necessary to write out the UI code twice?

```
- (void)showElement:(BOOL)animated
{
  if (animated) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
      // animation code
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
      // completion code
    }];
  } else {
    // animation code
    // completion code
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't remember the exact problem scenario I had but using this trick caused me some grief at one point in time - I now write this in a similar fashion to @SomeGuy.

Answer (score 3):

I write mine like this - it creates the block first and then either gives it to the UIView animation method or executes it by itself:

```
- (void) showElement:(BOOL) animated
{
    void (^animations)(void) = ^{
        //  animation code
    };

    if(animated)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:animations];
    }
    else
    {
        animations();
    }
}
```

Edit: You can also do the same with your completion block